# Filter array based on another array in f#

Tags: f#

If I have two arrays

```
let array1 = [|1;2;3;4|]
let array2 = [|2;3|]
```

how do i do a filter to just get all the elements in one from the other
e.g Give me all the items from array2 that are in array1 = 2 and 3

This is my attempt but is not correct

```
let result3 = array1 |> Array.filter(fun array1item -> array2 |> Array.filter(fun array1item2 -> array1item2 = array1item))
```

Update:
This works, not sure if its the best way

```
let result3 = array1 |> Array.filter(fun array1item -> array2 |> Array.exists(fun array1item2 -> array1item2 = array1item))
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `Set` module? If you just want do that, `Set.intersect` is perfect.

Comment: Cant use set as I have to use arrays. Don't think I can convert, do work and convert back

Comment: Change the inner `Array.filter` to `Array.exists` and you're there.

Comment: thanks ildjarn just spotted that myself and updated question

Comment: Instead of `Array.exists(fun array1item2 -> array1item2 = array1item)` use `Array.contains array1item`. Use `Array.exists` if you need a more complicated predicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As John Palmer suggests, using `Set.intersect` may be easier and more efficient, but I'm not sure the ordering would be guaranteed. You can filter arrays using `Array.exists`, but it's most likely going to be less efficient:

```
let result3 = array1 |> Array.filter (fun x -> array2 |> Array.contains x)
```

Comment: Mark, I am getting Array.contains is not defined. Is this because I am on f#3?

Comment: Yes, it was added in F# 4.0:
http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-39-71-metablogapi/3125.collectionAPI_5F00_254EA354.png

The new ones are marked in green.